# mysql-db request: how to get the db-name and the db-type as output of the request

Tags: php, mysql, linux, joomla, request

i have a mysql db with more than 60 tables. This was built while i was porting over a joomla version 2.5.3 from a local lamp to the webserver.

i run a mysql-db:

after porting over i saw that i cannot login the amdin-area. Well some tings couled have happened here.  What my question now is - how can i make a db-request that asks for the db-type...

```
Tabelle aufsteigend     Aktion  Zeilen  Typ     Kollation   Größe   Überhang
    oqlgu_assets    Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     47  InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     64,0 KiB    -
    oqlgu_associations  Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     0   InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     32,0 KiB    -
    oqlgu_banners   Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     0   InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     96,0 KiB    -
    oqlgu_banner_clients    Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     0   InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     48,0 KiB    -
    oqlgu_banner_tracks     Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     0   InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     64,0 KiB    -
    oqlgu_booklibrary   Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     6   MyISAM  utf8_general_ci     15,3 KiB    -
    oqlgu_booklibrary_categories    Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     10  MyISAM  utf8_general_ci     4,1 KiB     -
    oqlgu_booklibrary_lend  Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     0   MyISAM  utf8_general_ci     1,0 KiB     -
    oqlgu_booklibrary_lend_request  Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     0   MyISAM  utf8_general_ci     1,0 KiB     -
    oqlgu_booklibrary_main_categories   Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     6   MyISAM  utf8_general_ci     5,5 KiB     -
    oqlgu_booklibrary_review    Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     2   MyISAM  utf8_general_ci     4,1 KiB     -
    oqlgu_booklibrary_suggestion    Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     0   MyISAM  utf8_general_ci     1,0 KiB     -
    oqlgu_booklibrary_version   Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     1   MyISAM  utf8_general_ci     2,0 KiB     -
    oqlgu_categories    Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     7   InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     128,0 KiB   -
    oqlgu_contact_details   Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     0   InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     144,0 KiB   -
    oqlgu_content   Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     0   InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     144,0 KiB   -
    oqlgu_content_frontpage     Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     0   InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     16,0 KiB    -
    oqlgu_content_rating    Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     0   InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     16,0 KiB    -
    oqlgu_core_log_searches     Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     0   InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     16,0 KiB    -
    oqlgu_extensions    Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     136     InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     176,0 KiB   -
    oqlgu_finder_filters    Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     0   InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     16,0 KiB    -
    oqlgu_finder_links  Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     0   InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     112,0 KiB   -
    oqlgu_finder_links_terms0   Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     0   InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     48,0 KiB    -
    oqlgu_finder_links_terms1   Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     0   InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     48,0 KiB    -
    oqlgu_finder_links_terms2   Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     0   InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     48,0 KiB    -
    oqlgu_finder_links_terms3   Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     0   InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     48,0 KiB    -
    oqlgu_finder_links_terms4   Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     0   InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     48,0 KiB    -
    oqlgu_finder_links_terms5   Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     0   InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     48,0 KiB    -
    oqlgu_finder_links_terms6   Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     0   InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     48,0 KiB    -
    oqlgu_finder_links_terms7   Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     0   InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     48,0 KiB    -
    oqlgu_finder_links_terms8   Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     0   InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     48,0 KiB    -
    oqlgu_finder_links_terms9   Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     0   InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     48,0 KiB    -
    oqlgu_finder_links_termsa   Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     0   InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     48,0 KiB    -
    oqlgu_finder_links_termsb   Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     0   InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     48,0 KiB    -
    oqlgu_finder_links_termsc   Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     0   InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     48,0 KiB    -
    oqlgu_finder_links_termsd   Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     0   InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     48,0 KiB    -
    oqlgu_finder_links_termse   Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     0   InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     48,0 KiB    -
    oqlgu_finder_links_termsf   Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     0   InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     48,0 KiB    -
    oqlgu_finder_taxonomy   Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     1   InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     96,0 KiB    -
    oqlgu_finder_taxonomy_map   Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     0   InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     48,0 KiB    -
    oqlgu_finder_terms  Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     0   InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     80,0 KiB    -
    oqlgu_finder_terms_common   Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     115     InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     48,0 KiB    -
    oqlgu_finder_tokens     Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     0   MEMORY  utf8_general_ci     0 Bytes     -
    oqlgu_finder_tokens_aggregate   Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     0   MEMORY  utf8_general_ci     0 Bytes     -
    oqlgu_finder_types  Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     0   InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     32,0 KiB    -
    oqlgu_jaem_log  Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     0   MyISAM  utf8_general_ci     1,0 KiB     -
    oqlgu_jaem_services     Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     2   MyISAM  utf8_general_ci     2,1 KiB     -
    oqlgu_languages     Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     1   InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     80,0 KiB    -
    oqlgu_menu  Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     38  InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     128,0 KiB   -
    oqlgu_menu_types    Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     1   InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     32,0 KiB    -
    oqlgu_messages  Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     0   InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     32,0 KiB    -
    oqlgu_messages_cfg  Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     0   InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     16,0 KiB    -
    oqlgu_modules   Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     22  InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     64,0 KiB    -
    oqlgu_modules_menu  Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     21  InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     16,0 KiB    -
    oqlgu_newsfeeds     Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     0   InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     128,0 KiB   -
    oqlgu_overrider     Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     0   InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     16,0 KiB    -
    oqlgu_redirect_links    Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     0   InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     48,0 KiB    -
    oqlgu_schemas   Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     1   InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     16,0 KiB    -
    oqlgu_session   Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     2   InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     64,0 KiB    -
    oqlgu_template_styles   Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     6   InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     48,0 KiB    -
    oqlgu_updates   Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     0   InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     16,0 KiB    -
    oqlgu_update_categories     Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     0   InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     16,0 KiB    -
    oqlgu_update_sites  Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     3   InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     16,0 KiB    -
    oqlgu_update_sites_extensions   Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     4   InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     16,0 KiB    -
    oqlgu_usergroups    Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     8   InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     80,0 KiB    -
    oqlgu_users     Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     1   InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     96,0 KiB    -
    oqlgu_user_notes    Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     0   InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     48,0 KiB    -
    oqlgu_user_profiles     Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     0   InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     16,0 KiB    -
    oqlgu_user_usergroup_map    Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     1   InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     16,0 KiB    -
    oqlgu_viewlevels    Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     3   InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     32,0 KiB    -
    oqlgu_weblinks  Anzeigen Anzeigen   Struktur Struktur   Suche Suche     Einfügen Einfügen   Leeren Leeren   Löschen Löschen     0   InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     144,0 KiB   -
```

for the mysql-db: 
i want to have the following output - the table-name and the db-type...

is this doable!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, TABLE_TYPE, ENGINE FROM information_schema.tables WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'yourDbName';
```

you have to change **yourDbName** with the real name of your db.

Greatings.

Comment: hello dear jorge - many thanks for thge quick reply - i will try this out - and sorry for the messy output that i pasted in the thredstart